# Multiplication unit skips overflow bit during addition

Tags: vhdl, multiplication, waveform

I made a simple multiplication unit (16-bit operands, 32-bit result) based on the "shift-left, add" principle, and it does not work properly in the adder part when the overflow bit needs to be considered.

I have an idea what should be done (make a 17-bit sum vector and add an overflow bit to the product), but I don't know how to implement it. Below you can find the waveform file where I am showing the error location and the MPU.vhd file. The screenshot does not show the final result, but it is obvious that it will be wrong. How can I get it to work with large 16-bit numbers?

[image: Place where the overflow bit is skipped]

**MPU.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all; 

entity MPU_OP is
    port (C: in std_logic;    -- Clock
    RST : in std_logic;       -- Reset
    LAB : in std_logic;       -- Load A and B, P <= 0
    SHIFT : in std_logic;     -- Shift B and P
    OUTHL : in std_logic;     -- Output most(0) or least(1) significant word P
    DA : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);   -- Data A
    DB : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);   -- Data B
    DP : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)); -- Word result P
end entity;

architecture BEH of MPU_OP is
signal A, B : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); -- A, B
signal Pi, Ai, Si : integer;
signal S : signed(15 downto 0); -- Sum 
signal S2 : signed(16 downto 0);
signal P : signed(31 downto 0); -- Product

begin 
    RG_A : process(C, RST) -- Register for A
    begin
        if (RST = '1') then
            A <= X"0000";
        elsif rising_edge(C) then                                        `-- Reg_A`
            if LAB = '1' then
                A <= DA;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    RG_B : process(C, RST) -- Register for B
    begin
        if (RST = '1') then
            B <= X"0000";
        elsif rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                B <= DB;
            elsif (SHIFT = '1') then
                B <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(B), 1));       `-- Reg_B`
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    
    
    Adder : process (C)
    begin
        Pi <= to_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector(P(15 downto 0))));
        Ai <= to_integer(unsigned(A));

        if B(15) = '1' then
            S <= P(15 downto 0) + signed(A);                             -- Adder
            Si <= Pi + Ai;
        else
            S <= P(15 downto 0);    
            Si <= Pi;
        S2 <= to_signed(Si, S2'length); 
        end if;
    end process;

    
    RG_P : process (C, RST, P) -- Register for P   
    begin
        if RST = '1' then 
            P <= X"00000000";
        elsif rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                P <= X"00000000";
            elsif SHIFT = '1' then
                if B /= "1000000000000000" then
                    P <= P(30 downto 16) & S & '0'; -- Shift LEFT        `-- Reg_Product`
                else
                    P <= P(31 downto 16) & S;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    MUX_P : DP <= std_logic_vector(P(15 downto 0)) when OUTHL = '1' else
        std_logic_vector(P(31 downto 16));
    
end architecture;
```

Below is the minimal code to reproduce the above problem and the testbench for it.

**MPU.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all; 

entity MPU_TEST is
    port (C: in std_logic;
    LAB : in std_logic;
    SHIFT : in std_logic;
    DA : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DB : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DP : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture BEH of MPU_TEST is
signal A, B : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal S : signed(15 downto 0);
signal P : signed(31 downto 0); 

begin 
    RG_A : process(C)
    begin
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                A <= DA;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    RG_B : process(C) 
    begin 
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                B <= DB;
            elsif (SHIFT = '1') then
                B <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(B), 1));
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    
    
    Adder : process (C)
    begin
        if B(15) = '1' then
            S <= P(15 downto 0) + signed(A);
        else
            S <= P(15 downto 0);    
        end if;
    end process;

    
    RG_P : process (C, P) 
    begin 
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                P <= X"00000000";
            elsif SHIFT = '1' then
                if B /= "1000000000000000" then
                    P <= P(30 downto 16) & S & '0';
                else
                    P <= P(31 downto 16) & S;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    DP <= std_logic_vector(P);
end architecture;
```

**MPU_TB.vhd**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mpu_test_tb is
end mpu_test_tb;

architecture TB_ARCHITECTURE of mpu_test_tb is
    component mpu_test
    port(
        C : in STD_LOGIC;
        LAB : in STD_LOGIC;
        SHIFT : in STD_LOGIC;
        DA : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        DB : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        DP : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) );
    end component;


    signal C : STD_LOGIC;
    signal LAB : STD_LOGIC;
    signal SHIFT : STD_LOGIC;
    signal DA : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal DB : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);

    signal DP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);


begin


    UUT : mpu_test
        port map (
            C => C,
            LAB => LAB,
            SHIFT => SHIFT,
            DA => DA,
            DB => DB,
            DP => DP
        );

    process
    begin 
        C <= '0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        C <= '1';
        wait for 5 ns;
    end process;
    
    LAB <= '1', '0' after 10 ns;
    SHIFT <= '0', '1' after 10 ns, '0' after 170 ns;
    DA <= X"1234";
    DB <= X"F234";
    
end TB_ARCHITECTURE;
```

And a new signal with an incorrect multiplication result. The error occurs in adder.

[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Can your readers replicate the waveform? Note some of your process sensitivity lists are incomplete.

Comment: Your code here doesn't analyze. You can't enclose comments in grave accents.

Comment: Did you really want to use C as a latch enable instead of a clock?

Comment: @user1155120 I've updated the code to make it more minimalistic. I'm new to VHDL, so there will be flaws in my code.

Comment: is this an unsigned or signed multiplier?

Comment: @vipin unsigned, most likely. The main requirement is that it does left shift multiplication. And it is already doing its job, but the adder does not work on overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work. I explicitly added "0" when shifting the product and added a 17th bit to **S** to keep the overflow bit. Also, the signal ranges have been changed, which should be stored in the product and sum. Ended up with the code below.

**MPU.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all; 

entity MPU_TEST is
    port (C: in std_logic;
    LAB : in std_logic;
    SHIFT : in std_logic;
    DA : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DB : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DP : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture BEH of MPU_TEST is
signal A, B : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal S : signed(16 downto 0);
signal P : signed(31 downto 0); 

begin 
    RG_A : process(C)
    begin
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                A <= DA;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    RG_B : process(C) 
    begin 
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                B <= DB;
            elsif (SHIFT = '1') then
                B <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(B), 1));
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    
    
    Adder : process (C)
    begin
        if B(15) = '1' then
            S <= P(16 downto 0) + signed(A);
        else
            S <= P(16 downto 0);    
        end if;
    end process;

    
    RG_P : process (C, P) 
    begin 
        if rising_edge(C) then
            if LAB = '1' then
                P <= X"00000000";
            elsif SHIFT = '1' then
                if B /= "1000000000000000" then
                    P <= P(30 downto 17) & S & '0';
                else
                    P <= P(31 downto 17) & S;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    DP <= std_logic_vector(P);
end architecture;
```

Simulation screenshots of the correct waveforms
[image: First example]
[image: Second example]